# jQuery - override preventDefault() when click + ctrl pressed

Tags: jquery

I am using `preventDefault()` for preventing default behavior of an an anchor button, but I want to make this button to do default behavior when clicked with keyboard `ctrl` button,

**JS code**

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**HTML code**

```
<a href="http://google.com">Go to the best search engine</a>
```

Here is the playground: http://jsfiddle.net/sKDuA/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    if (!e.ctrlKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Other intertesting options:

- `e.altKey` - to check if <kbd>Alt</kbd> was pressed
- `e.shiftKey` - to check if <kbd>Shift</kbd> was pressed
- `e.button` - to distinguish between right, left of middle mouse clicks
- `e.which` - same as above, but also works for keyboard
- full documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

---

One more note, as you asked about documentation so seem to be really interested ;)

It's possible to debug in jsfiddle - just put `debugger` in your js code and run as usual. Your browser (I use Chrome) would stop on the debugging line, and you could examine the `e` object in the watches:

[image]

Comment: got one problem in firefox, how to use multiple key ctrl+alt, do you know any site where I can read documentation on on keyboard ?

Comment: Glad it worked. Note that you can also debug jsFiddle (as any other javascript) - might find this helpful.

Comment: You can use the `e.metaKey` on the mac to detect the `⌘ CMD` key

Answer (score 1):

If someone needs to fix this for both Mac and Windows this does the trick:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    if (!e.ctrlKey || !e.metaKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```